# No alert window appears after clicking 'Confirm'

Tags: javascript, html

This is my homework and this is my first time to do form validation.The following codes are my HTML code and JavaScript code respectively.

HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="validate_form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <form name="register" method="post" action="">
            <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="firstname"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Surname:</td><td><input type="text" id="surname"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Gender:</td><td><input type="text" id="gender"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Birthday - Day:</td><td><input type="text" id="dob"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Month:</td><td><input type="text" id="month"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Year:</td><td><input type="text" id="year"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yahoo ID:</td><td><input type="text" id="yahoo_id"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" id="password"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Retype password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="retype"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Question 1:</td><td><input type="text" id="q1"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Answer 1:</td><td><input type="text" id="a1"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Question 2:</td><td><input type="text" id="q2"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Answer 2:</td><td><input type="text" id="a2"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="validate_form ()"/></td><td></td></tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</body>



</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function validate_form () 

{
    var first = document.getElementById("firstname").value;  /*get value from the IDs*/
    var sur = document.getElementById("surname").value;
    var sex = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
    var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
    var yahooid = document.getElementById("yahoo_id").value;
    var ps = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var retype_ps = document.getElementById("retype").value;
    var ques1 = document.getElementById("q1").value;
    var ans1 = document.getElementById("a1").value;
    var ques2 = document.getElementById("q2").value;
    var ans2 = document.getElementById("a2").value;

    var error = "";                              /*Regular expressions for matching purpose*/
    var val_name = /^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$/;
    var val_dob = /^[0-9]$/;
    var val_yahoo = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]$/;
    var val_pass = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;

    if (first == null || surname == null || !val_name.test(first)  || !val_name.test(sur) ) /*Validate firstname and surname*/                   

    {
        error += "Invalid firstname and/or surname.\n";
    }

    else if (sex == null) /*Validate gender*/ 

    {
        error += "Invalid gender.\n";
    }

    else if  (day == null || !val_dob.test(day)) /*Validate day of birth*/ 

    {
        error += "Invalid day of birth.\n";
    }

    else if  (month == null) /*Validate month of birth*/ 

    {
        error += "Invalid month of birth.\n";
    }

    else if (year == null || !val_dob.test(year)) /*Validate year of birth*/ 

    {
        error += "Invalid year of birth.\n";
    }

    else if (yahooid == null || !val_yahoo.test(yahooid)) /*Validate Yahoo Id*/ 

    {
        error += "Invalid yahoo Id.\n";
    }

    else if (ps == null || !val_pass.test(ps)) /*Validate password entered*/ 

    {
        error += "Invalid password.\n";
    }

    else if (retype_ps == null || retype_ps != password) /*Validate retype password*/ 

    {
        error += "Retype password is different form password.\n";
    }

    else if (ques1 == null || ans1 == null || ques2 == null || ans2 == null) /*Validate question 1, answer 1, question 2, and answer 2*/ 

    {
        error += "Invalid Question 1 and/or Answer 1 and/or Question 2 and/or Answer 2.\n";
    }

    else if (error == "") /*If no error, display the following message*/ 

    {
        alert("Thank you for your registration.");
    }

    else /*If there are errors, display all the error messages*/

    {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

So,now the problem is what are wrong with the codes until the alert window did not appear?Hope the errors can be pointed out thoroughly because I am still new to JavaScript.

Comment: `alert{error};` should be `alert(error);`.

Comment: found just now and corrected.But the alert window still not appear.

Comment: Have you tried debugging you using the chrome debugger or firebug or IE's dev tools?

Comment: I just used Google Chrome to test it.

Comment: After I typed all the values to test,there was nothing to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you concatenate the messages in the variable `error` you have to do the last `else if` as an independent `if`:

```
...
else if (ques1 == null || ans1 == null || ques2 == null || ans2 == null)
{
  error += "Invalid Question 1 and/or Answer 1 and/or Question 2 and/or Answer 2.\n";
}

if (error == "") /*If no error, display the following message*/ 
{
  alert("Thank you for your registration.");
}
else /*If there are errors, display all the error messages*/
{
  alert(error);
}
```

NOTE: I've also noticed a mistake in the if of checking password repetition, you have changed its name (you named it `password` instead of `ps`).

I uploaded two samples in JSFiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/kcDBU/

This one have only `if` instead of `else if`:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/kcDBU/1/

Comment: I changed all 'else if' to 'if' and it works.But I wonder why I cannot use 'else if' instead of 'if'?

Comment: because at the first sign of an error you would NEVER get to the "ELSE"

Comment: as you do else if instead of single if everytime, you never get more than one message at once. try changing all else if for single if.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you've some values that are considered false:

> - false,
> - null,
> - undefined,
> - '',
> - 0,
> - NAN;

You've to consider that your value could be "undefined" too, so, if i were you, i would do this:

```
if (!first || !surname || !val_name.test(first)  || !val_name.test(sur) )                   
{
    error += "Invalid firstname and/or surname.\n";
}
```

And put your script at the end of your body tag.